# How do you resize a UITableViewController tableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Just your basic UITableViewController dragged in from interface builder.

[image]

The size controls are faded out. Why? Setting the frame in code doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

On Interface Builder, select `freeform` under your view controller parameters.
Then, you can edit the size as you tried.

[image: Right here]

Comment: No, you can only edit it's width and height. But he is asking to resize it, never asked how to edit the whole frame. ![Image here](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/5327/capturedecran1206131726.png).

Comment: And how to present it?What is the use of doing this way?Still need a UIViewcontroller to show it ?Right?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a UITableViewController

> Manages a UITableView, automatically creating an instance with the
>   correct dimensions and resizing mask, and acting as the table view's
>   delegate and data source.  The UITableViewController class also
>   provides toggling of editing modes.

It is supposed to be behaving so

Use `UIViewcontroller` and add the tableview along with delegate and datasource methods if you want to play with it in more customizable frame

Comment: Just add a `UITableView` to a plain `UIViewController`. Don't forget to set the delegate/dataSource either.